# Normal convergence of this function series

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence

I don't know how to solve this task:

Let $\mathbb{R}\_$ be the set of non-positive reel numbers and $U=\mathbb{C}\backslash\mathbb{R}\_$. For $n\ge 0$ consider the function $f_n=U \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ defined by $f_n(z)=(-1)^n / (z+n)$.
For $k\ge0$, set $g_k=f_{2k}+f_{2k+1}$. Show that $\sum_{k\ge0} g_k$ converges normally on $U$.

Well I tried this: $g_n=\frac{1}{z+2n} - \frac{1}{z+2n+1}=\frac{1}{(z+2n)(z+2n+1)}$, but this doesn't seem to be helpful so I decided to look at
$g_n=\frac{1}{z+2n} - \frac{1}{z+2n+1}$ and see what happens when $n \rightarrow \infty $ This seems to me, that it will go converges to 0. But now I have no Idea what to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $K\subset U$ is compact, then there is a constant $C$ (depending on $K$) such that
$$
|g_n(z)|=\frac{1}{|z+2\,n|\,|z+2\,n+1|}\le\frac{C}{n^2}\quad\forall z\in K.
$$
This implies that $\sum g_n(z)$ converges absolutely uniformly in $K$.